# Import classes from a Javascript library to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to import an external JavaScript library with no typings or installable package. The plugin is: https://github.com/amw/jpeg_camera/tree/master/dist/jpeg_camera_no_flash.js. I want to import three classes from that plugin: `JpegCamera`, `JpegCameraHTML5` and `Snapshot`. With the help of some tutorials, I was able to export the three classes with their interfaces in a `.d.ts` file. The .d.ts file looks something like:.

`declare module Camera {}

export class JpegCamera {...}

export class JpegCameraHTML5 {...}

export class Snapshot {...}`

Now, I don't know how to create a link between the plugin source file (.js), my own .d.ts file and the typescript file where I want to import these three classes. I tried
`import * as X from "path/to/d.ts`
but it won't work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which context you are running your application, but trying locally I got the message: `ReferenceError: document is not defined` loading with the syntax:
`import * as camera from './jpeg_camera_no_flash'`

You should not have this message if you are running your script through a browser.

> I downloaded the file physically to my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this:
`/// <reference path="path to the .d.ts" />`
Or you could export each class using `default`, so you can import them like this: `import className from './file-path'`

Comment: You mean in d.ts file do somthing like `export default class Main {  class JpegCamera{}...}`

Comment: nope. Something like this `export default class JpegCamera {...}`

Comment: It wont let use multiple default in same file. Maybe a outer wrapper class that uses default is what you meant.

Comment: create them in separate files. do you have to use on file?